# How Do I Column to Row?

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

```
CREATE TABLE `history_kw_main` (
`logdate` DATE NULL,
`logtime` TIME NULL,
`0h` INT(11) NULL,
`1h` INT(11) NULL,
`2h` INT(11) NULL,
`3h` INT(11) NULL,
`4h` INT(11) NULL,
`5h` INT(11) NULL,
`6h` INT(11) NULL,
`7h` INT(11) NULL,
`8h` INT(11) NULL,
`9h` INT(11) NULL,
`10h` INT(11) NULL,
`11h` INT(11) NULL,
`12h` INT(11) NULL,
`13h` INT(11) NULL,
`14h` INT(11) NULL,
`15h` INT(11) NULL,
`16h` INT(11) NULL,
`17h` INT(11) NULL,
`18h` INT(11) NULL,
`19h` INT(11) NULL,
`20h` INT(11) NULL,
`21h` INT(11) NULL,
`22h` INT(11) NULL,
`23h` INT(11) NULL,
UNIQUE INDEX `uix_kW_main` (`logdate`, `logtime`) USING BTREE);
```

There is a column representing 24 hours.
Data comes in every 15 minutes.
For example, at 10:15, the value is entered in the logtime column of the 10h column.
I want to add the values ​​of all columns based on logdate.
In other words,
I want to create a group with logdate and sum the values ​​for all time zones on that day.
How is there a way?

Comment: Sample data and desired results would be a big help.

Comment: Seriously consider revising your schema. A database table IS NOT a spreadsheet

Comment: I didn't make it. Was made by a partner company..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you just want aggregation?

```
select logdate,
       sum(`0h` + `1h` + `2h` + . . . `23h`) as day_total
from history_kw_main
group by logdate;
```

If the values can be `NULL`, you need to take that into account:

```
select logdate,
       sum(coalesce(`0h`, 0) + coalesce(`1h`, 0) + . . . coalesce(`23h`, 0)) as day_total
from history_kw_main
group by logdate;
```